# Create new elements from comma separated attribute values

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have XML. I would like to create new elements based on the attribute values.

Below is an example XML:

```
<MyRootElement>
 <MyTag id = "1" Range="2"/>
<MyTag id = "2,3" Range="2"/>
</MyRootElement>
```

I would like to separate the attribute values and create new elements. Basically convert the above to:

```
<MyRootElement>
 <MyTag id = "1" Range="2"/>
 <MyTag id = "2" Range="3"/>
 <MyTag id = "3" Range="3"/>
</MyRootElement>
```

My end goal is to convert each element into an object. I am doing the below to achieve the same:

```
    const string xmlstring = @"<MyRootElement>
     <MyTag id = '1' Range='2'/>
    <MyTag id = '2,3' Range='2'/>
    </MyRootElement>";

                var xmlConfig = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);
                if (xmlConfig.Root == null) return;

                var tags= xmlConfig.Root.Elements("MyTag");

var temp = tags.Select(t =>
            {
                var id = t.Attribute("Id");
                var range = t.Attribute("Range");
                return new
                {
                    ID = (id != null) ? int.Parse(id.Value) : 0,
                    Range = (range != null) ? int.Parse(range.Value) : 0,
                };
            });
```

But this fails if the attribute id has multiple values.
I would like to have three objects as the end result which will be like below:

```
  {
       ID= 1,
       Range = 2
   },
  {
       ID= 2,
       Range = 3
  },
  {
       ID= 3,
       Range = 3
  }
```

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Thank you for you help.

Comment: We would like you to share the code you wrote for this and tell us what issue you are facing with that code.

Comment: @kjhughes: I was not actually editing the content since it is clear. It was only added tags to characterize the question.

Comment: I have edited my question to include the code. Hope that makes question clear.

Comment: @kjhughes: xmldocument was mistake. I meant **XDocument** to modify childnodes. That wasn't a good edit. I agree. thanks for feedback.

Comment: How many different attributes are going to be comma separated?  Do you always want a unique id number for each element?  Your sample input and output are not consistent which makes this task impossible to do until you modify the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Linq method [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) allows you to return a new collection of elements for each element in your tags collection. You can combine this with a function for parsing the id tag value into a collection of ids in order to obtain your described functionality.

E.g.

```
var temp = tags.SelectMany(t =>
            {
                var id = t.Attribute("id");
                var range = t.Attribute("Range");
                var ids = (id != null) ? id.Value.Split(',').Select(int.Parse) : new[] { 0 };
                var rangeValue = (range != null) ? int.Parse(range.Value) : 0;
                return ids.Select(i => new { ID = i, Range = rangeValue });
            });
```

It's not entirely clear in your question whether the value of Range has any association with the number of values in the id tag, there's a discrepancy between your described input and output.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.. this helps.